# $\lim (x_n^k) = (\lim x_n)^k$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Question: Prove that if $x_n$ is a convergent sequence, $k \in N$, then $\lim (x_n^k) = (\lim x_n)^k$. Hint: use induction.

Let $\lim x_n = x.$ Then, $(\lim x_n)^k = x^k$. So, I have to show that $\lim (x_n^k)=x^k$.

Do I have to show this $|x_n^k-x^k| < \varepsilon$ by using induction?? I can't proceed from here. Could you give some hint??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: i also would try induction over $k$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It concerns induction on $k$.

Prove (or apply if it is at your disposal allready) that: $$[a_n\to a\text{ and }b_n\to b]\implies[a_nb_n\to ab]$$

Then the induction step will be

$$[x_n^{k-1}\to x^{k-1}\text{ and } x_n\to x]\implies[x_n^k=x_n^{k-1}x_n\to x^{k-1}x=x^k]$$

Comment: I get it. Thanks. :)

Comment: You are very welcome.